# Linq SelectMany.Distinct.ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for some input with this error. I am clear about a few things but not sure how to fix this linq expression. This error happens for our users and I can't reproduce this problem. So I tried to find where we use distinct operator with selectmany and found one occurrence in the routine.

```
  var finishedReqs = allDocs.SelectMany(x => x.Reqs).Distinct().ToList();
  var finishedReqsWithDocs = finishedReqs.Where(x => x.Docs.Any());
  if (finishedReqsWithDocs.Any())
     {
     //Call another routine
     }
Exception
-----------------
Message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I understand that if the collection is null, SelectMany returns null instead of an empty list. And then I am confused because we do a Distinct.ToList(). Where do I need to check for nulls. Resharper tells me the first expression with Distinct.ToList() can never be null

```
if(finishedReqs!=null) //Resharper has squiggly lines with expression is always true
{
}
```

Comment: is `allDocs` a IQueryable object, for example from EntityFramework, or is it just a normal IEnumerable object?

Comment: Also your statement *"I understand that if the collection is null, SelectMany returns null instead of an empty list."* that is not true. if the collection is null [it throws a `ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: It is a List<Document>

Comment: ok thanks for correcting me..But what could be the problem? Any ideas. In a sense it is returning a null exception. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Add a where filter before the select many. Check that reqs is not null. I had written an extension method to return empty collection is collection if null for situations like this.

Comment: Check if one of the item in allDocs isn't null

Comment: @Nkosi: So you think in this line var finishedReqs = allDocs.SelectMany(x => x.Reqs).Distinct().ToList(); Reqs could be null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not `finishedReqs` that is null, it is one of the entries inside of `allDocs` that is null.

If you look at the stack trace the top layer is

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__14`2.MoveNext()

That means it is failing inside of `Enumerable.SelectManyIterator`. Somewhere in `allDocs` it is holding a null `Document` object.

If the error was instead that `x.Reqs` was null the top layer of your exception would be located inside the anonymous lambda expression in your code.

The way to fix it is exclude any null documents before you do the `SelectMany`

```
allDocs.Where(x=> x != null).SelectMany(x => x.Reqs).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: But why is it complaning about Distinct..at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()

Comment: Thank you. Can I mark both as answers?

Comment: Because the thing that actually fires the request is the .ToList() because both `SelectMany()` and `Distinct()` are lazily evaluated. so when you go to actually perform the evaluation it has to travel through the `.ToList()` (your bottom layer), call the List constructor (the next layer), evaluate the enumarable passed in to the constructor (the layer with the `.Distinct()` because that is the outer most thing), then process the SelectMany.

Comment: @user575219 Honestly the answer you picked is wrong, it will still give the error because it is not `Reqs` that is null, it is `x` and he never checks for that..

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying.

Comment: Thank you. I was inclined towards this. And this may be can happen sometimes

Comment: I did both. allDocs.Where(x=> x != null).Where(x => x.Reqs != null).SelectMany(x => x.Reqs).Distinct().ToList(); May be I could combine both the Where to allDocs.Where(x => x != null && x.Reqs!=null)

Comment: Yes, you could combine the Where clauses if you wanted, but it does not really cause much overhead so its fine to leave them separate if you find it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Reqs` collection of one of the documents is null. Try check for null like this:

`var finishedReqs = allDocs.SelectMany(x => x.Reqs ?? new Request[0]).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: I don't want to create an empty list. Can I add a where clause to only select not null values

Comment: Sure. Try this: `var finishedReqs = allDocs.Where(x => x.Reqs != null).SelectMany(x => x.Reqs).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Thank you. Honestly this should never happen. But thank you.